# WPF Print infragistics Report without PrintDialog

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, report, infragistics

I am working on WPF which uses Infragistics dll for report Generation and printing.

```
<igWPF:TabItemEx Name="tabEvent" Header="{x:Static p:resource.tab_reports_events}" >
            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Button Content="{x:Static p:resource.tab_report_print}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnAllEventPrint_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0,10,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Name="btnPrintAllEvent"/>
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="30,0,0,10">

                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:resource.tab_report_to}"  Style="{StaticResource WPFTextBlockStyle}" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                    <ig:XamDateTimeInput  Name="dtTo" Margin="10,0,0,0" Value="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now}"/>
                    <Button Content="{x:Static p:resource.tab_report_buttongo}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnSearch_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>

<dataPresenter:XamDataGrid x:Name="datagdEvent" DataSource="{Binding EventList}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  GroupByAreaLocation="None" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Visibility="Hidden" >
                    <dataPresenter:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                        <dataPresenter:FieldLayoutSettings RecordSelectorLocation="None" AllowAddNew="False" AllowDelete="False" AutoGenerateFields="False"  />
                    </dataPresenter:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
                    <dataPresenter:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                        <dataPresenter:FieldLayout >
                            <dataPresenter:FieldLayout.Fields>
                                <dataPresenter:Field Name="Machine" Label="{x:Static p:resource.tab_report_machine}" Width="0.6*">
                                    <dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                        <dataPresenter:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelTextAlignment="Center" EditorStyle="{StaticResource TextEditor}" />
                                    </dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                </dataPresenter:Field>
                                <dataPresenter:Field Name="HouseNumber" Label="{x:Static p:resource.tab_houseNumber_Title}" Width="0.36*">
                                    <dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                        <dataPresenter:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False" LabelTextAlignment="Center" EditorStyle="{StaticResource TextEditor}" />
                                    </dataPresenter:Field.Settings>
                                </dataPresenter:Field>
                            </dataPresenter:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        </dataPresenter:FieldLayout>
                    </dataPresenter:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                </dataPresenter:XamDataGrid>
            </DockPanel>
        </igWPF:TabItemEx>
```

On the Click of the Print Button this below function is fired :btnAllEventPrint_Click

```
private void btnAllEventPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            Report reportObj = new Report();
            reportObj.ReportSettings.HorizontalPaginationMode = HorizontalPaginationMode.Scale;
            reportObj.PageHeaderTemplate = this.Resources["PagePresenterHeaderTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            string siteControllerName = RedeemVoucherView.getSiteControllerName();
            reportObj.PageHeader = siteControllerName;
            reportObj.ReportSettings.PageSize = new Size(3.15, 4);
            reportObj.ReportSettings.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            reportObj.Sections.Add(section);
            reportObj.Print(false, false);

            //reportObj.Print(true, false);
```

}

*//public void Print(bool showPrintDialog, bool showReportProgressControl);*

The Print function with **showDialog=false** gives me error and does not print the report.Tried with 2-3 types of printer

***Error: Argument Exception was caught.96.85' is not a valid value for property 'Width'.
'-80.9759842519685' is not a valid value for property 'Width'.***

I am able to print the document successfully with the **showdialog** value set to true with any printer.

I would like the report to be printed with the **default printer** without selecting the printer name /without dialog box selection menu.

*How can i acheive this? Am I missing something on this:*

Comment: You mean the showDialog=false gives you an error, right? Because these two sentences contradict each other: "The Print function with showDialog=true gives me error and does not print the report.Tried with 2-3 types of printer" AND "I am able to print the document successfully with the showdialog value set to true with any printer."

Comment: Updated the Post.."showDialog=false gives an error"

Comment: What happens if you remove the `reportObj.ReportSettings.PageSize = new Size(3.15, 4);` line? Or try to set it to a higher value for example: `reportObj.ReportSettings.PageSize = new Size(1000, 1000);`?

Comment: In both the cases it gets printed(incrasing the size/excluding that line).But I am not sure whether the contents will be fit properly in the printer which is basically used to print these reports(Epson U220D Thermal Sales Printer)..